# Favicon issue in IE

Tags: html, internet-explorer, favicon

```
<link rel="icon" 
      href="../../Content/favicon.ico" />
```

This displays our favicon in every browser except IE (9 included). Why isn't it showing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `shortcut icon` instead of just `icon`:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon"
      href="../../Content/favicon.ico" />
```